# When would using a systematic random sample bias tests of inference?

Tags: sampling, inference

I understand that an underlying assumption for parametric statistical inference (t-test, ANOVA, etc.) is that there needs to be a [simple random sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) from a population. However, I'm not sure how using a [systematic random sample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systematic_sampling) might be different than a simple random sample, and how this impacts inference.

For example, if I use a systematic random sample (e.g., *select a sample of students using the last digit of their student ID*) vs. a simple random sample (e.g., *drawing 10% of the student population out of a hat*) aren't these essentially equivalent for inference?

**Under what conditions would using a systematic random sample for inference be "ok", and under what conditions would it be "bad"?**

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen that, but the wikipedia article you mention gives several examples of systematic sampling misuse (e.g. see the corner houses example). Do you need some further explanation of these examples? Have you simply missed them? Or is your question about something else entirely?

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed it! So the intuition is that systemic sampling is fine as long as: 1) the sampling interval doesn't correlate with any covariates and 2) if the population isn't evenly divisible for small samples with large sampling intervals?